# Calculating variance of a simple expression with sympy random variables

Tags: random, probability, sympy

Two U(0,1) random variables, X1 and X2, and I want the variance of max(2,X1)+X2.

And I want it using sympy. Yes, I know it's too easy. However, I would like to know if there are built-in ways of handling problems like this one, and how to use them.

```
>>> from sympy.stats import Uniform, Variance
>>> from sympy import symbols, Integral
>>> X1 = Uniform('X1', 0, 1)
>>> X2 = Uniform('X2', 0, 1)
```

sympy seems to dislike `max`; it expresses the same distaste for the `if` statement.

```
>>> Variance(max(2, X1) + X2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy-1.0.1.dev0-py3.4.egg\sympy\core\relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

The problem is trivial, though, and I could simplify it sufficiently.

```
>>> Variance(2 + X2)
Variance(X2 + 2)
>>> Variance(2 + X2).evaluate_integral()
1/12
```

I am usually pretty thick unfortunately. How would I handle probability calculations involving conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `max` doesn't work with SymPy objects; use SymPy's [Max](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#max) instead. Also, you don't need to use passive (un-evaluated) form `Variance` and then ask for its evaluation: just use `variance` which attempts evaluation. Example:

```
from sympy.stats import Uniform, variance, E
from sympy import Max
X1 = Uniform('X1', 0, 1)
X2 = Uniform('X2', 0, 1)
X3 = Max(2, X1) + X2
print(E(X3))
print(variance(X3))
```

This sort of works, except the integrals seem too hard to be to be evaluated anyway, as they contain Max. This is the output.

```
1/2 + Integral(Max(2, X1), (X1, 0, 1))
2*Integral(Max(2, X1), (X1, 0))*Integral(Max(2, X1), (X1, 0, 1)) - 2*Integral(Max(2, X1), (X1, 1))*Integral(Max(2, X1), (X1, 0, 1)) - Integral(Max(2, X1)**2, (X1, 0)) + Integral(Max(2, X1)**2, (X1, 1)) + 1/12 + Integral(Max(2, X1), (X1, 0, 1))**2
```

Forcing a numeric answer works for expected value:

```
print(E(X3).evalf())
```

prints 2.5. The only way I found to get a numeric value for variance is by sampling - that is, ask SymPy to generate a sample of given size and take variance from there, subject to sampling errors of course.

```
print(variance(X3, numsamples=1e4))
```

prints 0.0839550029765917.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you're right. I will express due regret if someone comes along and I'm obliged to accept that person's answer. But I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: When piecewise-defined functions and computer algebra systems are involved, I am pleasantly surprised when something goes right at all. In this specific situation, the main obstacle is that even `integrate(Max(x, 2), (x, 0, 1))` returns un-evaluated by SymPy.

Comment: Nice to know that it's not just human beings that have difficulty with them.